# Aligning and sizing images inside tabularx cells

Tags: graphics, tabularx, adjustbox

For the following, why does `graphbox` top-align the image better than `adjustbox`?

Additionally, how to make `width=\columnwidth` work as expected?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{graphbox,duckuments,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
        }% adjustbox
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,valign=T]{example-image-a}
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
        }% graphbox
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,align=t]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

Why doesn't `width=\columnwidth` work as expected unlike `width=\linewidth` in the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{graphbox,duckuments,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
        }
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
        }
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You use different image anchor. Replace `valign=T` with `valign=t`,an you will see, that result are indentical. Also why `{
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X` ? Simpler and more corect is `{XX}˙...

Comment: Column width refers to the width of a column in a two column document, not to the width of a table column. To achieve the latter, use hsize instead of columnwidth

Comment: It is important that the total `\hsize` of all `X` columns is $n$ times `\hsize` with $n$ the number of `X` columns. Also it is best to set `\hsize=<share>\hsize\linewidth=\hsize` with `<share>` a float.

Comment: @Skillmon I am sorry, would you please give me an example with numbers to see how `\hsize=<share>\hsize\linewidth=\hsize` works in practice?

Comment: `>{\hsize=0.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X` for two `X` type columns and the second one taking 3 times the width of the first one. The reason you want to also set `\linewidth` locally is to ensure that many LaTeX macros/environments would use the correct width.

Comment: @Skillmon Please, take a look at my edit.

Comment: @Diaa `\columnwidth` is *not* the width of the current column in a table, but the width of a single column in a multi-column document similar to how `\textwidth` is usually the width of the text block. The width of the current surrounding box (e.g. in `\parbox`, a `minipage`, etc.) is usually `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare apples with pears ... If you replace `valign=T` with `valign=t` (as was suggested in Schrödinger's cat now deleted answer), than you will get the very same result:

[image]

Off-topic: Why you use `{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}` for column specifications? Simpler and more correct is `{XX}˙:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}% adjustbox
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}% graphbox
        \blindduck[1] & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the first fix. Why doesn't \columnwidth work as expected?

Comment: @Diaa, how you expect that it would work? I doubt that its length is equal to `\textwidth/2 -2*\tabcollsep` what is width of one column in table.

Comment: I was lazy to change `{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}` into another meaningful example. For `width=\columnwidth`, I expect it to change the image width to be equal to that of the column which is `0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep` where it didn't happen, so I wondered why. I would be grateful if you explain why it didn't.

Comment: Please, take a look at my edit to know what I mean.

Comment: @Diaa, your question become unclear what is you problem. From original version follows, that is difference in positioning image in table. This is solved by my answer. All other is *off-topic*. If my suggestion in *off-topic* part of answer make you (new) problems, please ask new question, where clarify, what is the problem. Note: `\columnwidth` is width of text in two (or more) column text. It has nothing common with widths of columns in tables.

Comment: I don't ask off-topic questions, bit it seems that I can't explain well enough. Anyway, thanks for your answer and help.